Transience In Lattice Walks Generalization
Just out of curiosity, I heard that a random lattice walk is only transient in one and two dimensions. I wonder if there is a generalization of this: Let $P$ be a probability distribution over $\mathbf{Z}_{>0}$ of the first return time in one dimension. Let there be $n$ independent random sequences $X^i$ such that $X^i_{j+1}-X^i_j$ is $P$-distributed. Then asking for transience in $n$ dimensions corresponds to the probability of the existence of an $n$-tuple $j(i)$ such that all $X^i_{j(i)}$ align being $1$. But this can be asked for $P$s which don't arise from a random walk as well. Is this a meaningful measure, the largest $n$ for which such tuples always exist? Can it be extended to rational numbers for a more fine grained assessment?
